# Elastic Collision of a rod which can move and rotate with a particle obliquely

Tags: collision

I am facing trouble with the following question

A rod $AC$ of length $l$ and mass $m$ is kept on a horizontal smooth surface. It is free to rotate and move. A particle of same mass $m$ moving on the plane with velocity $v$ strikes rod at $B$ elastically as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The question is to find the angular velocity of the rod and its final velocity.

Attempt

I tried basically by applying conservation of energy , linear momentum and angular momentum.

Let the final situation be something like this

[image]

Now conservation of energy gives $$1/2mv^2=1/2m(v_5^2+v_6^2)+1/2m(v_3^2+v_4^2)+1/2(1/12ml^2w^2)$$

and conservation of angular momentum $$m(4v/5)(3l/4)=(1/12ml^2w^ 2)w-mv_4(3l/4)$$

and by linear momentum in two directions $$ 3v/4=v_3+v_6$$ and $$4v/5=v_5-v_4$$

But I have 5 unknowns and I could manage only 4 equations. Moreover solving these equations is lengthy and I think there must be some quicker way to solve this being a  entrance exam question with time restrictions. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens to the incoming mass after collision? Is the collision elastic or inelastic?

Comment: @Farcher sorry I forgot to mention that collision is elastic. Nothing is known about the velocity of incoming mass after collision.

Comment: If the collision is elastic then the incoming mass can impart no linear momentum to the bar along the direction of the long axis of the bar.

Comment: @Farcher how can we say that? The collision is oblique in nature.

Comment: Which forces causes a change in momentum along the axis of the rod?

Comment: @Farcher Ah!  that means that the horizontal component of the velocity of incoming mass remains unchanged and the rod moves perpendicular to itself . This reduces two unknowns. Thanks.

Comment: @Farcher I have one confusion . what would be the expression of coefficient of restitution in this case . will it depend on w? Thanks.

Comment: If a collision is perfectly elastic it is one. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution

Comment: @Farcher I know it is 1. But the expression that is what would be the velocity of separation.

Comment: Forget about the coefficient of restitution if you are not sure about it and use conservation of kinetic energy. Then having solved the problem go back to coefficient of restitution knowing the answers and see what need to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Im not solving the whole question but u can also write the missing equation for cofficient of resistution

$e=\frac{\text{Velocity   of   sepration}}{\text{Velocity   of   approach}}$

($e=1$ for elastic collision)

And I think this question can also solved by conserving angular momentum about point of collision as Net torque about all the forces are 0 about this point.If you like you can also use Impulse momentum theorem though it will produce same result as yours.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to know if velocity of saparartion depends in w.

Comment: Use conventional translatory motion approach. e  has no relation with $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this kind of problem is to find the reduced mass of the rod along the contact normal.

### Problem Setup

Consider the general situation below. A moving rigid body is impacted by a sphere. The motion of the rigid body is tracked by the location $\vec{r}_1$, velocity $\vec{v}_1$ of the center of mass and the rotational velocity $\vec{\omega}_1$. The impact occurs on some point **A** with location $\vec{r}_A$, and along the contact normal direction $\hat{n}$. The response depends on the vector $\vec{c} = \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_A$ describing the location of the center of mass relative to the contact point.

[image: fig]

After the impact, there is a step in motion of the center of mass described by the vectors $\Delta \vec{v}_1$ and $\Delta \vec{\omega}_1$. The impact consists of an exchange of momentum with magnitude $J$ (called an impulse) along the contact normal $\hat{n}$ such that $$\begin{aligned} \Delta \vec{v}_1 & = \tfrac{1}{m_1} \hat{n} J \\ \Delta \vec{\omega}_1 & = \mathrm{I}_1^{-1} ( -\vec{c} \times \hat{n} J) \end{aligned} \tag{1}$$

### General 3D solution

The kinematics of the contact point **A** after the impact defines the impulse magnitude $J$. Before impact, the speed of approach is

$$v_{\rm imp} = \hat{n} \cdot( \vec{v}_1 + \vec{c} \times \vec{\omega}_1 - \vec{v}_2 ) \tag{2}$$

where $\vec{v}_2$ is the velocity of the impacting body. And after the impact the speed of release is equal and opposite of the speed of approach for an elastic contact.

$$ v_{\rm rel}  = - v_{\rm imp} $$

or the change in speed must be twice the impact speed

$$  \hat{n} \cdot(\Delta \vec{v}_1 + \vec{c} \times \Delta \vec{\omega}_1 - \Delta \vec{v}_2 ) = - 2 \hat{n} \cdot( \vec{v}_1 + \vec{c} \times \vec{\omega}_1 - \vec{v}_2 ) \tag{3}$$

Use (1) in (3) to find $J$ as

$$ J = \frac{2 \hat{n} \cdot( \vec{v}_1 + \vec{c} \times \vec{\omega}_1 - \vec{v}_2 )}{\frac{1}{m_1}-\hat{n}\cdot(\vec{c}\times \mathrm{I}_1^{-1} \vec{c}\times \vec{n}) + \frac{1}{m_2}}  $$

or how I prefer to state it

$$ J = 2\; m_{\rm imp}\; v_{\rm imp} \tag{5} $$

with the *reduced mass* defined as $$m_{\rm imp} = \left( \tfrac{1}{m_1}-\hat{n}\cdot(\vec{c}\times \mathrm{I}_1^{-1} \vec{c}\times \vec{n}) + \tfrac{1}{m_2} \right)^{-1} \tag{6}$$

Notice that for two spheres the above reduces to $m_{\rm imp} = \left( \tfrac{1}{m_1} + \tfrac{1}{m_2} \right)^{-1}$ which is a well known formula.

Once $J$ is known, then the motion afterward is calculated from (1)

### Planar Projection

Now to make the planar projection of the above with $\hat{n} = \pmatrix{n_x \\ n_y}$ and $\vec{c} = \pmatrix{c_x \\ c_y}$

and use it in (6) to get

$$ m_{\rm imp} = \left( \frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{(c_x n_y - c_y n_x)^2}{I_1} + \frac{1}{m_2} \right)^{-1} \tag{7}$$

And the change motion from (1) and (5) in 2D

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \Delta \vec{v}_1 & = \pmatrix{ \tfrac{n_x}{m_1} J \\ \tfrac{n_y}{m_1} J } \\
  \Delta \omega_1 & = \tfrac{n_x c_y - n_y c_x}{I_1} J
\end{aligned} \tag{8}$$

### Specific Problem

The solution to the question is found by using the following geometry

$$ \begin{aligned}
  I_1 & = \tfrac{m}{12} \ell^2 \\
  \vec{c} & = \pmatrix{-\tfrac{\ell}{4} \\ 0} \\
  \vec{n} & = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1}
\end{aligned} $$

which results in $m_{\rm imp} = \left( \frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{3}{4 m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2} \right)^{-1}$ and so to get $J$ from (5) and the motion from (1).

The choice of $\hat{n} = \pmatrix{0\\1}$ is because the contact normal has to be normal to both surfaces, and thus perpendicular to the rod. It would be a mistake to *assume* that $\hat{n}$ must be parallel to the impacting velocity $\vec{v}_2$ which as you can see in my diagram they are at an angle to each other.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you write the equations shortly after the collision .
you obtain:

\begin{align*}
\left[ \begin {array}{c} J_{{r}} \left(\dot\varphi _{{{\it rf}}}-\dot
\varphi _{{{\it ri}}} \right) =P\sin \left( \alpha \right) L
\\  m \left( {\it \dot{x}}_{{{\it rf}}}-{\it \dot{x}}_{{{\it ri
}}} \right) =P\,\cos(\alpha)\\  m \left( {\it \dot{y}}_{{{\it rf}}}-{
\it \dot{y}}_{{{\it ri}}} \right) =P\sin \left( \alpha \right)
\\  m \left( v_{{{\it bf}}}-v_{{{\it bi}}} \right) =-
P\\  \cos(\alpha)\dot{x}_{rf}+\sin(\alpha)\left(L\,\dot{\varphi}_{rf}
+\dot{y}_{rf}\right)=v_{bf} \quad\quad (**)\end {array} \right]\tag 1
\end{align*}

with $~L=\frac 14 l~,$ P is the linear momentum

$~,i~$ stay for initial , $~f~$ for final $~r~$ rod and $~b~$ for ball

you have 5 equations (Eq. (1)) for 5 unknowns $~\dot\varphi_{rf}~,v_{bf}~,\dot{x}_{rf}~,\dot{y}_{rf}~,P~$ .

**the velocity at the contact point**

\begin{align*}
  \left(\left(\begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       0 \\
       \dot{\varphi}_{rf} \\
     \end{bmatrix}\times
     \begin{bmatrix}
       L \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}\right)+
     \begin{bmatrix}
       \dot{x}_{re} \\
       \dot{y}_{re} \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}\right)^T 
     \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos(\alpha) \\
       \sin(\alpha) \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}=v_{bf}\quad\quad (**)
\end{align*}